# Android BLE not discovering services on my MSP432 SensorHub

Tags: android, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been trying to figure out why my code does not want to find services of my MSP432 SensorHub example (MSP432 + CC2650 BoosterPack + Sensor BoosterPack stack). Will show the code and logcat below.

```
public class SensorOutput extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "Data Output";

    private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    private TextView mTemp;

    /* Temp Service */
    private static final UUID TEMP_SERVICE = UUID.fromString("f000aa00-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
    private static final UUID TEMP_DATA = UUID.fromString("f000aa01-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
    private static final UUID TEMP_CONFIG = UUID.fromString("f000aa02-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");

    /* Humidity Service */
    public static final UUID HUMIDITY_SERVICE = UUID.fromString("f000aa20-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
    public static final UUID HUMIDITY_DATA = UUID.fromString("f000aa21-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
    public static final UUID HUMIDITY_CONFIG = UUID.fromString("f000aa22-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");

    /* Barometer Service */
    public static final UUID BAROMETER_SERVICE = UUID.fromString("f000aa40-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
    public static final UUID BAROMETER_DATA = UUID.fromString("f000aa41-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
    public static final UUID BAROMETER_CONFIG = UUID.fromString("f000aa42-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");

    /* Optical Service */
    public static final UUID OPTIC_SERVICE = UUID.fromString("f000aa70-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
    public static final UUID OPTIC_DATA = UUID.fromString("f000aa71-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
    public static final UUID OPTIC_CONFIG = UUID.fromString("f000aa72-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");

    /* Movement Service */
    public static final UUID MOVEMENT_SERVICE = UUID.fromString("f000aa80-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
    public static final UUID MOVEMENT_DATA = UUID.fromString("f000aa81-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
    public static final UUID MOVEMENT_CONFIG = UUID.fromString("f000aa82-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");

    /* Client Configuration Descriptor */
    private static final UUID CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data);
        mTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperatureData);

        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgress.setCancelable(false);

        BluetoothDevice device = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("Bluetooth_Device");
        connect(device);
    }

    public void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(SensorOutput.this, false, mGattCallback);
            mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
        }
    }

    public final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

        /* State Machine Tracking */
        private int mState = 0;

        private void reset() { mState = 0; }

        private void advance() { mState++; }

        /*
         * Send an enable command to each sensor by writing a configuration
         * characteristic.  This is specific to the SensorTag to keep power
         * low by disabling sensors you aren't using.
         */
        private void enableNextSensor(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
            switch (mState) {
                case 0:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Enabling temperature");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(TEMP_SERVICE)
                            .getCharacteristic(TEMP_CONFIG);
                    characteristic.setValue(new byte[] {0x01});
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Enabling optic");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(OPTIC_SERVICE)
                            .getCharacteristic(OPTIC_CONFIG);
                    characteristic.setValue(new byte[] {0x01});
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Enabling barometer");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(BAROMETER_SERVICE)
                            .getCharacteristic(BAROMETER_CONFIG);
                    characteristic.setValue(new byte[] {0x01});
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Enabling humidity");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(HUMIDITY_SERVICE)
                            .getCharacteristic(HUMIDITY_CONFIG);
                    characteristic.setValue(new byte[] {0x01});
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Enabling movement");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(MOVEMENT_SERVICE)
                            .getCharacteristic(MOVEMENT_CONFIG);
                    characteristic.setValue(new byte[] {0x01});
                    break;
                default:
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_DISMISS);
                    Log.i(TAG, "All Sensors Enabled");
                    return;
            }

            gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }
        /*
         * Read the data characteristic's value for each sensor explicitly
         */
        private void readNextSensor(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
            switch (mState) {
                case 0:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Reading temperature");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(TEMP_SERVICE)
                            .getCharacteristic(TEMP_DATA);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Reading optic");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(OPTIC_SERVICE)
                            .getCharacteristic(OPTIC_DATA);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Reading barometer");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(BAROMETER_SERVICE)
                            .getCharacteristic(BAROMETER_DATA);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Reading humidity");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(HUMIDITY_SERVICE)
                            .getCharacteristic(HUMIDITY_DATA);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Reading movement");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(MOVEMENT_SERVICE)
                            .getCharacteristic(MOVEMENT_DATA);
                    break;

                default:
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_DISMISS);
                    Log.i(TAG, "All Sensors Enabled");
                    return;
            }

            gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }

        /*
         * Enable notification of changes on the data characteristic for each sensor
         * by writing the ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE flag to that characteristic's
         * configuration descriptor.
         */
        private void setNotifyNextSensor(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
            switch (mState) {
                case 0:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Set notify temperature");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(TEMP_SERVICE)
                            .getCharacteristic(TEMP_DATA);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Set notify optic");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(OPTIC_SERVICE)
                            .getCharacteristic(OPTIC_DATA);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Set notify barometer");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(BAROMETER_SERVICE)
                            .getCharacteristic(BAROMETER_DATA);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Set notify humidity");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(HUMIDITY_CONFIG)
                            .getCharacteristic(HUMIDITY_DATA);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Set notify movement");
                    characteristic = gatt.getService(MOVEMENT_CONFIG)
                            .getCharacteristic(MOVEMENT_DATA);
                    break;
                default:
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_DISMISS);
                    Log.i(TAG, "All Sensors Enabled");
                    return;
            }
            //Enable local notifications
            gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            //Enabled remote notifications
            BluetoothGattDescriptor desc = characteristic.getDescriptor(CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR);
            desc.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            gatt.writeDescriptor(desc);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connection State Change: " + status + " -> " + connectionState(newState));
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                /*
                 * Once successfully connected, we must next discover all the services on the
                 * device before we can read and write their characteristics.
                 */
                gatt.discoverServices();
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_PROGRESS, "Discovering Services..."));
            } else if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                /*
                 * If at any point we disconnect, send a message to clear the weather values
                 * out of the UI
                 */
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_CLEAR);
            } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                /*
                 * If there is a failure at any stage, simply disconnect
                 */
                gatt.disconnect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Services Discovered: " + status);

                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_PROGRESS, "Enabling Sensors..."));
                /*
                 * With services discovered, we are going to reset our state machine and start
                 * working through the sensors we need to enable
                 */
                reset();
                enableNextSensor(gatt);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            //For each read, pass the data up to the UI thread to update the display
            if (TEMP_DATA.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_TEMP, characteristic));
            }
            if (OPTIC_DATA.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_OPTIC, characteristic));
            }
            if (BAROMETER_DATA.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_BAROMETER, characteristic));
            }
            if (HUMIDITY_DATA.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_HUMIDITY, characteristic));
            }
            if (MOVEMENT_DATA.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_MOVEMENT, characteristic));
            }

            //After reading the initial value, next we enable notifications
            setNotifyNextSensor(gatt);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            //After writing the enable flag, next we read the initial value
            readNextSensor(gatt);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            /*
             * After notifications are enabled, all updates from the device on characteristic
             * value changes will be posted here.  Similar to read, we hand these up to the
             * UI thread to update the display.
             */
            if (TEMP_DATA.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_TEMP, characteristic));
            }
            if (OPTIC_DATA.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_OPTIC, characteristic));
            }
            if (BAROMETER_DATA.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_BAROMETER, characteristic));
            }
            if (HUMIDITY_DATA.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_HUMIDITY, characteristic));
            }
            if (MOVEMENT_DATA.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_MOVEMENT, characteristic));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            //Once notifications are enabled, we move to the next sensor and start over with enable
            advance();
            enableNextSensor(gatt);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Remote RSSI: "+rssi);
        }

        private String connectionState(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    return "Connected";
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    return "Disconnected";
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    return "Connecting";
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTING:
                    return "Disconnecting";
                default:
                    return String.valueOf(status);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Log cat:

> D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() -
>   Device=A0:E6:F8:BA:2D:XX interval=6 status=0
>
> D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=A0:E6:F8:BA:2D:XX
>   Status=0
>
> D/Data Output: Services Discovered: 0
>
> D/Data Output: Enabling temperature
>
> D/Data Output: Reading temperature
>
> D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() -
>   Device=A0:E6:F8:BA:2D:XX interval=39 status=0

Comment: The device is being discovered from scan activity and taken as intent to next activity. 
Link to whole project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EDnwUl5zOK5wnsWFVz1elIyCFrDM7Ifz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Project was finished in June.
https://github.com/gruwy/MSP432TTUBLEDatalogger